# Who interviewed whom?

Tags: history

The [Vikipedio article on Steve Allen](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Allen) says that Steve Allen interviewed Esperantist
[William Harmon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_R._Harmon) about Esperanto, but I would have thought it would be the other way around.

Is this just a glitch in Vikipedio, or was the format of the interview deliberately skewed that way?

Comment: Huh? What's unusual about a "television personality" being the interviewer and someone involved in the topic of the film (here: an esperantist) being the interviewee? That seems quite common in documentaries and informational movies.

Comment: I guess you’re right on the surface of it, but if a TV celebrity had initiated an Esperanto event, I’m pretty sure that that itself, quite apart from the event, would have been big news in the Esperanto community, and an enduring ‘bargaining chip’ in later discussions about introducing Esperanto here or there into mainstream society. I have a dim recollection of seeing part of the interview, and being under the impression that it was an attempt, just barely successful, on the part of Bill Harmon to get this TV celebrity to give thumbs-up to Esperanto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a promotional video, paid for by ELNA (according the the description of ELNA's video fund which was still active in at least 2008) - and so the format was basically Steve Allen lent his celebrity to the project. Bill Harmon lent his knowledge of the World of Esperanto. With that in mind, it only makes sense that it was Harmon who was being interviewed as a way to get his knowledge out to the viewers.

Comment: So, the direction of motion was globally from Harmon to Allen, but locally from Allen to Harmon.